# Dynamicaly rounding numbers in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, math, rounding

I know that there are many different questions about this sort of topic on SO already, but I couldn't find a way to tailor them all to my specific needs.

What I have is a floating point number that gets sent to me through the network that I need to convert and graph out to the screen. The numbers can range from 5.2, 285.159, 294729172.258, -10734.112, etc. What I would like to do is get the value used to round from one digit below the most significant digit.

Example:

```
5.2 = 5
285.159 = 300
294729172.258 = 300000000
-10734.112 = -11000
```

Any advice that can be used to help guide me would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: And 294729172.258 to 300000000? You have to define a rounding criteria, and do your rounding function.

Comment: I would think that 5.2 = 5 but something like 5.5 = 6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's my solution:

```
int roundMostSignificant(float input)
{
    NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:input];
    static NSNumberFormatter *formatter = nil;

    if (!formatter)
    {
        formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
        [formatter setMinimumSignificantDigits:1];
        [formatter setMaximumSignificantDigits:1];
        [formatter setUsesSignificantDigits:YES];
    }

    return [[formatter numberFromString:[formatter stringFromNumber:number]] intValue];
}
```

Yes, this uses objects, but I think that this will be your best bet in the long run, as it handles rounding, parsing, etc. for you.

Comment: You sir are god like for this. Thank you so much! If possible could you explain what this is doing in the background or point me to documentation describing this process? I would like to learn as much as I can.

Comment: +1. And @Seb, this gives `-10000` for `-10734.112` which is more logical than the result you mentioned: `-11000`.

Comment: @Seb what this does is it first, takes a floating point number as input. Then, it converts that floating point number to a string, which is rounded to 1 significant digit, then it recreates a number from that string, and returns that number.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `NSDecimalNumber` and `NSDecimalNumberHandler` classes which does just that. You can define to which precision and to which direction the numbers should be rounded.

Simple example might be:

```
NSDecimalNumber *dn = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithMatnissa:294729172258 exponent:-3 isNegative:NO];
NSDecimalNumberHandler *dnh = [NSDecimalNumberHandler decimalNumberHandlerWithRoundingMode:NSRoundPlain scale:-6 raiseOnExactness:NO raiseOnOverflow:NO raiseOnUnderflow:NO raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];

NSDecimalNumber *rounded = [dn decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:dnh];
```

This would probably work for your biggest number.